# Sass Mixins Not Available in bootstrap-sass Project

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sass, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-sass

I have a Rails 4 project with `bootstrap-sass` and mixins like `border-radius(3px)` are unrecognized. I'm not certain what I'm doing wrong, but here are what I think are the relevant file parts:

```
// myfile.css.scss
@import "bootstrap";

#hotel-form {
  display: none;
  border: 1px gray solid;
  padding: 1em;
  margin-top: 2em;
  @include border-radius(3px);
}
```

I shouldn't need to import bootstrap in the above but I did it anyhow to try to get the `border-radius` mixin to be recognized.

```
# Gemfile
... lots of other stuff
gem 'bootstrap-sass', github: 'thomas-mcdonald/bootstrap-sass'
... and more other stuff

// application.css
*= require_self
*= require_tree .
```

I don't know if `application.css` is the problem. I get bootstrap from a CDN as follows:

```
-# application.html.haml

= stylesheet_link_tag "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
= javascript_include_tag "//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
```

I've tried every different combination other than installing bootstrap on my dev machine with no joy. Any pointers appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: There is no border-radius mixin?

Comment: Ahhhhh. Removed in Bootstrap 3. Hmmmm. So I get to write my own. Sigh.

Comment: Use an existing library?  http://compass-style.org/

Comment: Compass is pretty heavy for what I'm doing. I know caching clears some of that up, but each new client grabs my Compass-enhanced stylesheet which is usually pretty big if I'm using mixins.